# Meaning of "graded $R$-modules" in May's "A Concise Course in Algebraic Topology" on Page 89

Tags: definition, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, graded-modules

The confusing passage is also [here](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/MISC/TorExt.pdf) on page 2. May's usage of graded $R$-modules appears to differ from the standard definition, as far as I can tell. He is taking graded $R$-modules to mean the sequence of homology groups. Is this sequence actually a graded module, or is this just an idiosyncratic definition?

Comment: I suppose the definition given in Lang's $\textit{Algebra}$ Revised Third Edition Page 427: For $A$ a graded ring, the $A$-module $E$ is graded if $E = \coprod_{n=0}^\infty E_n$ such that $A_nE_m \subset E_{n+m}$.

Comment: Sounds fine: a graded module is a sequence of modules. Straightforward, unfussy and informal. The homology groups of a complex is a classic example.

Comment: The paper literally states that their approach is non-standard. "We understand “graded R-modules” to be sequences of R-modules such as
this (and we never take the sum of elements in different gradings)." But the difference is still just as Eric Wofsey describes

Comment: @ThomasChansler https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Graded_module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sequences of modules and graded modules (over a non-graded ring) are completely interchangeable. 
 Given any (non-graded) ring $R$ and a sequence $(A_n)$ of $R$-modules, the direct sum $\bigoplus_n A_n$ is a graded $R$-module, with the degree $n$ part just being $A_n$.  Conversely, a graded module (up to isomorphism) is determined by the sequence of its degree $n$ parts.  So, since the homology modules of a chain complex are a sequence of modules, they can also be thought of as a graded module.  (Explicitly, if you define a graded module as a module with a direct sum decomposition, the graded module is the direct sum of all the homology modules.)

(Of course, the direct sum $\bigoplus_n A_n$ does have one major advantage over the bare sequence $(A_n)$, in that you can talk about elements of $\bigoplus A_n$ that are not elements of any single $A_n$.  May explicitly mentions that he will not ever need to do this ("we never take the sum of elements in different gradings"), and so there is no loss of convenience in thinking of the graded module as just a sequence.)

Comment: Wouldn't you need the ring to be graded? How would you have $A_nE_m \subset E_{n+m}$ for the sequence?

Comment: I'd say the advantage (if it is one) of the direct sum is that graded module is in fact a module ...

Comment: @ThomasChansler: No, May is talking about graded modules over a non-graded ring $R$.  That's just an $R$-module with a direct sum decomposition, with no other restrictions.  (Or, if you like, it is a graded module over $R$ thought of as a graded ring by saying everything has degree $0$.)